# Webpack: how to structure page-level scripts

Tags: javascript, webpack, es6-modules

I have an application that has about 100 pages/routes.  About half of these pages have some javascript at the bottom, anything from 5 to 100 lines.  The javascript makes heavy use of jQuery, and other libraries such as jQuery UI, Bootstrap's JS, moment,js, the Typeahead bundle, etc.

I need to add some Vue.js components here and there, so I am going to take the opportunity to move to Webpack (for bundling), and ES6.

My question is, how should I structure the in-page javascript?  I would like to move it to Webpack, so that I can take advantage of ES6, apart from anything else.  Should I think in terms of 1 html page/route = 1 module?  Should I place all the modules in a single js file?  Should I be configuring it as a webpack library?

Unless I am mistaken, the calls to my packaged code will still need to come from my html body.  Also, I like the idea of namespacing, e.g. though custom objects, to keep things readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a single file for all the page-level scripts, which exports a single module.  This is a simple object, which I use for name spacing, as follows.

```
export default {

    helpers : {

        alert : msg => { /* ... */ },
        calendar : selector => { /* ... */ }

    },

    siteSection1 : {

        pageNameLorum : {
            methodA() { /* ... */ },
            methodB() { /* ... */ }
        },

        pageNameIpsum : {
            methodA() { /* ... */ },
            methodB() { /* ... */ }
        }
    }
}
```

This seems to work quite well.